# How to understand the reflect macro?

Tags: nodeos

`FC_REFLECT( eosio::history_apis::read_only::get_actions_params, (account_name)(pos)(offset) )`

I don't understand the reflect macro, and don't know where the macro was applied. Could anybody help me?